# How can I do screen recording with an internal voice in flutter and save that video on mobile storage?

Tags: flutter, voice-recording, screen-recording

How can I do screen recording with an internal voice in flutter and save that video on mobile storage? I have used the device_screen_recorder package but could not find any solution. I am using this package example code for doing it. please help me. I am new in a flutter.

Comment: there are two ohter packages, 1: `flutter_screen_recording`   2: `screen_recorder`

Comment: I have tried both of them but could find any solution for that.